# Can I run two motors using a shared common conductor?

Tags: power, transformer, motor, cables

Is it possible to independently run two motors using a shared common conductor?

The arrangement is:

- there are two motors, each has an external transformer: from mains power down to 24V (I think it is 24 VAC, not 24 VDC)
- the input to each motor only requires a two core cable (the black and pink inputs in the diagram below)
- I have an existing 3 core cable between the location of the transformers and the location of the two motors. The 3-core is 2.5mm2, so I think it can carry 20A.
- the distance between the transformers and motors is about 10-15m
- the motors are for moving a pair of sliding gates, so they need to be operated at the same time, but independently.
- the motors consume 50-70W
- the duty cycle is very low: the motors may run for 30 seconds at a time, and a few times per day.

Can I use the existing 3 core cable to power the two motors, by sharing the common wire (the pink lines in the diagram below)?

[image: attachment]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 24VAC or VDC?  What is the power/current consumption of the motors?  What is the gauge of the cable?  What temperature is the insulation rated for?  Are the motors going to be operated at the same time?  For how long?  What is the duty cycle?

Comment: @vir I think 24V AC. Motor power consumption is 50W. The 3-core cable is 2.5mm2, so I think it can carry 20A. Yes the motors will be run at the same time, for about 30 seconds at a time, possibly a few times per day, so the duty cycle is very low.

Comment: @John Can you [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/707784/edit) the question to include the information from your previous comment. Details should be in the question body and not comments.

Comment: @ChesterGillon Good point - I have updated the question as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrically it's possible.

I'm assuming the transformer outputs (and motor inputs) are not grounded, and that the cable is thick enough for the currents that will flow.